# Create Button to change background

Tags: java

I am trying to create a button in Android Studio that will allow users to change their background to whatever then want. I created the button but I do not know how to implement the background change function

Comment: Can we see what you have so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Learn [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you do so. In those questions learn how to properly provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: I have just created the button I am not sure of setting the functionality of the button